# Serving an excel file from compojure

Tags: excel, clojure, compojure

I want to serve an excel file from compojure. My objective is to open a template excel file in the resources folder of my compojure project, modify it and then serve it as a response.

Loading the file is easy:

```
(defn download-xls []
  (let [template-file (io/file (io/resource "template.xls"))
        fio (FileInputStream. template-file)
        workbook (HSSFWorkbook. fio)]
```

Then I perform some modifications to the content of the file using HSSF. The question is how do I return it as a response?

Thanks

Comment: you wanna serve it as a downloadable file?

Comment: Yes, I want to serve it as a downloadable file.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988486/serving-binary-files-from-the-database-with-compojure), or any other google posts searching "how to serve binary file in compojure"